# Java. The order of threads execution

Tags: java, multithreading

I try to run the example from a book(Paul Hyde, Java Thread Programming). It says that the order of threads will interchange. But I always get : 10 "Main thread" prints and 10 "New thread" ones afterwards.
What is more interesting : if I will use tt.run instead of tt.start then result will be vice versa. Maybe the reason that the book is quite old and examples are base on JDK 1.2??? Code is below:

```
public class TwoThread extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("New thread");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TwoThread tt = new TwoThread();
        tt.start();

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Main thread");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use `tt.run();` you only have a single thread (and it will print "New thread" first since you call that method first). It's the `start();` call that creates and starts an actual new thread of execution.

Comment: try looping till 1000 and you'll know.

Comment: Yes, it works if loop much more times.

Comment: You should never make assumptions about threads execution order. That's why synchronization primitives exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JVM decides when to transfer control from the main thread to the second thread. Since the main thread doesn't perform much work after starting the second thread, it makes sense the JVM lets it complete its work before trasfering control to the second thread.

When you use `tt.run()` instead of `tt.start()` you are not starting a second thread. You are executing the `run()` method in the main thread. Therefore you see the `"New thread"` outputs first.

Comment: also depends if the machine has multi-core processor and if it supports hyper-threading

Comment: The JVM doesn't "transfer control" between threads, it runs them both. Even on single-core non-ht processors, the ordering is completely random once both threads are running (on any OS doing preemptive multitasking). The reason for the somewhat predictable ordering in Leo's example is thread startup time.

Answer (score 1):

> if I will use tt.run instead of tt.start then result will be vice versa.

`tt.run` runs in `main` thread only whereas `tt.start` spawns another thread. Hence the result is expected.

> On seeing consistency:

for smaller and quick activities you may see consistent result occasioanly but that doesn't mean the order of print you are seeing is guaranteed. Increase loop iteration to higher number and see the order of print (say printing upto 10000 times)