# Order of thread execution in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have doubts about order of Thread execution in java. 
This example

```
  public class Thr implements Runnable {
    String string = "Yes ";
    public void run(){
      this.string = "No ";
    }
    public static void main (String args[]){
      Thr t = new Thr();
      new Thread(t).start();
      for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
          System.out.println(t.string);
    } 
  }
```

gives output :

```
Yes 
No 
No 
No 
No 
No 
No 
No 
No 
No
```

I have red this topic
[Java. The order of threads execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558678/java-the-order-of-threads-execution)
and I am confused why string is changed to no after first pass through for loop.
I tought that , as main thread doesn't have large job to do, main thread will execute first, and that output will be

```
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes 
Yes
No
```

When I put some print in run method instead this.string = "No" then, print from run method prints last.

Comment: Yes, but I thought that , as main thread doesn't have much job, firs for loop will be executed with Yes, and then       new Thread(t).start();
, so it will be yes and at the end, no

Comment: But when I put, for example, in run System.out.println("Thread"), and in for loop in main System.out.println("Main"), program prints string Thread at the end

Comment: Threads run independently of each other. There is no defined order and it may very well happen what you expected. But it's pure luck if you rely on that.

Comment: On top of a race issue (the relative order of execution of the instructions), this code exhibits a visibility issue (when will the write to the `string` variable be visible to the main thread). So, yeah, trully ANYTHING can happen here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that I figured out what is happening. Thing is, that this threads , main thread and new Thread(t) are both executing parallely. And it is kind of lottery, because they both make request for processor time, so, as main thread begin to execute, with all code that it needs to execute, main thread spend processor time, and it only prints first yes, and then new Thread(t) gets his processor time, changes "yes" to no, and finish execution, and than main thread again continue to execute. I've made a little test, and in

```
public class Thr implements Runnable {
  String string = "Yes ";
  public void run(){
    this.string = "No ";
  }
  public static void main (String args[]){
  Thr t = new Thr();
  Thread tr = new Thread(t);
  tr.start();
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
      System.out.println(t.string + tr.isAlive());
  } 
}
```

and the output is

```
Yes true
No false
No false
No false
No false
No false
No false
No false
No false
No false
```

Answer (score 0):

When working with threads be sure of one thing, you can't predict when a thread will start even if you call this:

```
new Thread(t).start();
```

When you call it the thread enter in a state that is "Ready to start running or Runnable state" and then the thread scheduler can take the thread and put it in a running state IF HE WANTS, it's a little bit complex but you can't predict what will happen when you have a bunch of them, sometimes if you start two threads the last would run first. For more understanding of the topic see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm)

Comment: I am aware of that, but I was just confused why in case with this.string = "no" in run it changes only after first iteration, and for all other actions it first executes main thread for a while... Even if I put 5000 iterations, it still changes from yes to no after first iteration. Is it posible that JVM executes run sooner as it doesn't contain a lot of job to do?

Comment: The ONLY thing you can know is that it is not specified what will happen.  Writing any code that depends on threads executing in a specific order, or one thread executing before another, without specific synchronization calls, is guaranteed to fail at some point. Don't do it, and then you won't have to worry about it.

Comment: I am painfuly aware of that either :D, but this is my java exam example, so I can not avoid that :)

Comment: Yeah, it's cool to play with threads, try to print the value and then put a wait with few time to see what happens :)